What's the easiest way to prove the Riemann Zeta function has any zeros at all on the critical line?
I learned in my intro to complex analysis class that the Riemann Zeta has trivial zeros at the negative even integers; this follows from the Riemann Zeta Reflection identity and the behavior of the $\Gamma$ function on negative integers. According to Wikipedia, Hardy proved there are infinitely many zeros on the critical line $Re(z) = \frac{1}{2}$, and apparently Riemann "checked that a few of the zeros lay on the critical line..." But to bridge the complexity gap here, is there an easy way to see 1. that $\zeta$ has other zeros at all besides these trivial ones, and 2. that it has any zeros at all on the critical line? How can I verify at home a prospective root?

The easiest way is to refer to the Hardy $Z$ function,
$$ Z(t) = e^{i \theta(t)} \zeta(1/2 + it), $$
where
$$ e^{i \theta(t)} = \pi^{-i t / 2} \frac{\Gamma(1/4 + it/2)}{\lvert \Gamma(1/4 + it/2) \rvert}.$$
It's not hard to show that $Z(t)$ is real when $t$ is real, and clearly $\lvert Z(t) \rvert = \lvert \zeta(1/2 + it) \rvert$. Hence they have the same zeros.
Thus one way to show that $\zeta(s)$ has a zero on the half-line is to find a value of $Z(t)$ that is positive, and another value that is negative: then there is a zero somewhere in the middle. Further, repeatedly computing and bisecting allows you to compute a zero to any desired precision.

Can you show how to compute Z(t) for some example value of t? Presumably, calculating an approximation is good enough, provided you still know the sign afterwards.

@quarague Do we take for granted that we can compute $\Gamma(s)$? I assume so. If not, then good approximations to the gamma function can be approximated reasonably well via numerical integration. A better approximation comes from the Lanczos approximation. For $\zeta(1/2 + it)$, using the simple eta function $\eta(s) = \sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^{n+1}/n^s$ and the immediate-upon-consideration relationship $\eta(s) = (1 - 2^{1-s}) \zeta(s)$ lets you compute $\zeta(1/2 + it)$, as $\eta(s)$ converges for $\mathrm{Re}(s) > 0$. Euler acceleration improves this. Euler-Maclaurin... (continued)

(continued)... Euler-Maclaurin would also work. There are a wealth of methods to compute $\zeta$. The approximate functional equation works well, and for $\zeta(s)$ there is a particularly nice form called the Riemann-Siegel formula. This is less obvious, but numerically much better behaved. In practice, one would use the Odlyzko-Schonhage algorithm to find lots of zeros to high precision quickly.
